# MongoDB - return documents AND count matched by a query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to return the matching documents from a mongo query as well as the number of matching documents. Is there a way to do this with one query?

The code I'm currently using to return the documents looks something like below, and I need to return all times an employee appears in a collection as well as the documents itself:

```
db.collection.find({employeeNumber: employeeNumber})
```

And I know to return the count would be to do something like:

```
db.collection.countDocuments({employeeNumber: employeeNumber})
```

Any help would be appreciated as my mongo knowledge is fairly basic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an aggregation query using [$facet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to get an output similar to:

```json
{
  "documents": [/*your documents matched*/],
  "count": X
}
```

So you can do:

- First `$match` to get desired results.
- Then `$facet` to create two outputs, one the match itself and another the number of documents using `$count`.
- And last two steps are to format the result and output in that format.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "employeeNumber": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "documents": [],
      "count": [{"$count": "count"}]
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "count": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$count",0]}
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "documents": 1,
      "count": "$count.count"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sj5fxrgTqC1)

Comment: I get the following error when I try to apply this to my code:

"sub-pipeline in $facet stage cannot be empty"

I will donate/buy you a coffee if you can help solve :)

Comment: I think you can add a `$match` stage to not be empty like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a4qa35oC5TH)

Comment: Thanks! Just donated via buymeacoffee :)